# How can I create an aggregated fuzzy set from responses?

Tags: r

I have over 360 responses filled in the google forms. The responses are ratings of alternatives/scenarios for water resources management. In the sample data frame below, the scenarios are labelled SC1 to SC10, and the responses are labelled R1 to R10.

df:

```
Scenarios,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10
SC1,3,2,3,9,2,7,4,8,6,6
SC2,7,5,2,7,3,7,2,7,8,5
SC3,8,5,3,9,6,9,3,5,6,6
SC4,9,8,4,9,6,9,8,7,5,7
SC5,2,4,3,5,5,9,7,5,7,5
SC6,9,9,6,9,6,9,8,5,7,8
SC7,6,8,5,5,7,9,8,6,6,7
SC8,5,5,4,6,8,9,7,7,5,6
SC9,8,6,6,8,6,9,8,7,7,7
SC10,5,2,5,9,5,9,7,6,4,6
```

I want to present the above table using fuzzy numbers with nine-point scale which is given as follows.

[image]

For example, in the provided data frame Responses for R9 and R10, can be presented as follows.

[image]

Lastly, I would like to create an aggregated data frame whereby the value for the first term (left) for a particular scenario, is taken as minimum value from all responses for that scenario, the second value (middle) is taken as the average of middle values from all responses in that scenario and the third term (right) is taken as maximum values from all responses for that scenario. The example results for the R9 and R10 responses are given as follows.

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the first ask. What does `(1, 1, 1)` mean?

Comment: Those are fuzzy set numbers representing linguistic terms of equal importance. The table is the standard table representing fuzzy sets.

Comment: Pretend I don't know what a fuzzy set is.

Comment: Let's assume they are just numbers representing lower and upper bonds between a certain renumber (response rating). Say, if a response is 3 the resulting set will have 2 as lower bound and 4 as upper bound while 3 is middle value ie, 3 = (2,3,4) except for 1 and 9, they are presented as (1.1,1) and (8,9,9).

Comment: So you want to take each rating, add plus/minus 1, then for each SC, find the min/max of that new, expanded range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`. It involves creating temporary columns and then concatenating the temp columns using `unite()`. I have left the Rn columns to allow validation. You can remove these using the `select()` function as with the temp columns. Note that I have modified your example data in order to illustrate what happens when values are either 1 or 9:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- read.csv(text = "Scenarios,R1,R2,R3,R4,R5,R6,R7,R8,R9,R10
SC1,3,2,3,9,2,7,4,8,6,6
SC2,7,5,2,7,3,7,2,7,8,5
SC3,8,5,3,9,6,9,3,5,6,6
SC4,9,8,4,9,6,9,8,7,5,7
SC5,2,4,3,5,5,9,7,5,7,5
SC6,9,9,6,9,6,9,8,5,7,8
SC7,6,8,5,5,7,9,8,6,6,7
SC8,5,5,4,6,8,9,7,7,5,6
SC9,8,6,6,8,6,9,8,7,1,7
SC10,5,2,5,9,5,9,7,6,4,9", header = TRUE)

result <- df %>%
  select(Scenarios, R9, R10) %>% # Variables of interest
  mutate(temp1 = rowMeans(select(., starts_with("R")), na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(temp2 = min(across(starts_with("R"))-1),
         temp3 = max(across(starts_with("R")))+1) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("temp"), ~ifelse(.x == 0,  1,
                                          ifelse(.x == 10, 9,
                                                 .x)))) %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("R"), ~ifelse(.x == 1,  paste0("1,1,1"),
                                          ifelse(.x == 9, paste0("8,9,9"),
                                          paste(.x-1, .x, .x+1, sep = ","))))) %>%
  unite(aggregate, c(temp2, temp1, temp3), remove = FALSE, sep = ",") %>%
  select(-starts_with("temp"))


data.frame(result)
   Scenarios    R9   R10 aggregate
1        SC1 5,6,7 5,6,7     5,6,7
2        SC2 7,8,9 4,5,6   4,6.5,9
3        SC3 5,6,7 5,6,7     5,6,7
4        SC4 4,5,6 6,7,8     4,6,8
5        SC5 6,7,8 4,5,6     4,6,8
6        SC6 6,7,8 7,8,9   6,7.5,9
7        SC7 5,6,7 6,7,8   5,6.5,8
8        SC8 4,5,6 5,6,7   4,5.5,7
9        SC9 1,1,1 6,7,8     1,4,8
10      SC10 3,4,5 8,9,9   3,6.5,9 

# Result from your original example data
   Scenarios    R9   R10 aggregate
1        SC1 5,6,7 5,6,7     5,6,7
2        SC2 7,8,9 4,5,6   4,6.5,9
3        SC3 5,6,7 5,6,7     5,6,7
4        SC4 4,5,6 6,7,8     4,6,8
5        SC5 6,7,8 4,5,6     4,6,8
6        SC6 6,7,8 7,8,9   6,7.5,9
7        SC7 5,6,7 6,7,8   5,6.5,8
8        SC8 4,5,6 5,6,7   4,5.5,7
9        SC9 6,7,8 6,7,8     6,7,8
10      SC10 3,4,5 5,6,7     3,5,7
```